# Unable to change backlight level

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, monitors, manjaro, backlight

In Manjaro I can't set the backlight. I've tried to add: `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor` to the kernel's command line but it didn't work.

And I also added `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"` to the `xorg.conf`, but it didn't work. Why?

Comment: Which machine and video card?

Comment: sony vaio vpceh1m1e, and nvidia geforce 410m

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution. I had to create two files in xorg.conf.d directory. 60-monitor.conf, and 60-screen.conf. Then I generated a xorg.conf file with the nvidia driver (nvidia-xconfig). I copied the monitor section into the 60-monitor.conf file, and the screen section to the 60-screen.conf file. Plus I added the plus two lines, which were mentioned above.